# What's Domain Type is Azure use?

Tags: azure, dns

I’m using *App Service Domain* in **Azure**,
As I know, there are *gTLDs* and *ccTLDs* domains,
which of them is **Azure** use?
Thanks!

Comment: Why does it matter? All TLDs work on the technical level absolutely in the same way.

Comment: Hi, I need to transfer a domain from Azure to another registrant, and there was the question "which type of domain I need to import"

Comment: So the problem is absolutely not about which "kind" of TLD it is but what restrictions there are on registrant changes. You can find eligibility rules in both gTLDs and ccTLDs, because it is not a technical matter, but an administrative one. So knowing if it is a gTLD or ccTLD does not help at all in your case.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I learned that .com domains are gTLDs from domain registrant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mix. Currently the following TLD's are supported in Azure Service Domains: com, net, co.uk, org, nl, in, biz, org.uk, and co.in.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain#basics-tab